# Question on Inverse Function Theorem Application

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ such that $f(x,y)=(x^2y+x, 6x+y^2)$.

What can we say about the existence of inverse of $f$ at $(x_1,y_1)=(1,1)$ and at $(x_2,y_2)=(-1,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(Jf)(x,y)=det(\frac{\partial( f_{1},f_{2})}{\partial (x,y)})$$

$$f_{1}(x,y)=x^{2}y+x$$

$$f_{2}(x,y)=6x+y^2$$

$$(Jf)(x,y)=2y(2xy+1)-6x^2$$

$$(Jf)(1,1)=0$$

$$(Jf)(-1,1)=-8$$

By the inverse function theorem we are guaranteed that $f(x,y)$ is invertible at $(-1,1)$. At $(1,1)$ the inverse function theorem has less to say, since it is not a necessary that the determinant of the Jacobian be nonzero for the function to be locally invertible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobian matrix is $$J=\begin{pmatrix}
2xy+1 & x^2 \\
6 & 2y
\end{pmatrix}
$$ its determinant is $$\det J = 4xy^2+2y-6x^2$$
$\det J=0$ at $(1,1)$ and hence at this point IFT is inconclusive, while $\det J = -8 \neq 0$ at $(-1,1)$, therefore there is a neighborhood $U$ of $(-1,1)$ in which the function $f$ is invertible.